# Discord bot return searched message on external page Python

Tags: python, web, discord, bots

I want creating a Discord Bot to help us verify people from our site in our discord.
I start creating a bot that search for a div from a URL but it seems it is always returning Message not found.
I can kinda new to pyhton.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

TOKEN = '********'
PREFIX = '%'

# Define the necessary intents
intents = discord.Intents.all()

# Create an instance of the bot with intents
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
print(f'Bot {client.user} ready!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.author == client.user:
    return

if message.content.startswith(f'{PREFIX}search'):
    # Get the search term from the message
    search_term = message.content[len(f'{PREFIX}search'):].strip()

    # Perform the search on the external page
    search_result = search_message_on_external_page(search_term)

    # Send the result back to the Discord server
    await message.channel.send(f'Search result for "{search_term}": {search_result}')

def search_message_on_external_page(search_term):
# URL of the external page containing the chat
url = 'https://rbxgold.com'

# Make the HTTP request to get the page content
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the content of the page with BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Replace this with the specific logic of your page
    messages = soup.find_all('div', class_='class="BaseElement Box ChatMessageSlide mention-    false col-true padding-top-2 padding-bottom-2"')  # Example message class

    # Debugging output
    print(f'Number of messages found: {len(messages)}')
    for i, message in enumerate(messages):
        print(f'Message {i + 1}: {message.text}')

        if search_term.lower() in message.text.lower():
            return f'Message found: {message.text}'

    return 'Message not found'
  else:
    return f'Error accessing the external page. Status code: {response.status_code}'


 client.run(TOKEN)
```

I don't know why it isn't returning any value, I tested and the message in on that same div

Comment: maybe first create function with `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` and test it on some values - and use `print()` to debug it. And later use this function in `discord`

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: you should check if web page works in web browser when you turn off `JavaScript` (and run it in `private mode` to work without `cookies`) because `requests` and `Beautifulsoup` can't run `JavaScript` and they don't logging on page, and they don't keep cookies.

Comment: I run `https://rbxgold.com` without `JavaScript` and it shows only `"You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."`. You may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`. Or you should check if this page has `API` and if this `API` can gives you needed data - and then you can use `requests` (and you don't need `Beautifulsoup` because `API` usually gives data in `JSON` format)